# (tkinter) Is there a problem with the way I'm griding buttons to a frame?

Tags: python, tkinter

So basically I'm making an mp3 player in tkinter and I want the user to be able to add playlists (buttons). I've added a (add playlists) button with a plus icon in the frame as you can see, that calls a function to pop up a window for the user to input the name of the new playlist.
[image]

I'm clicking the button and the 'Add Playlists' window pops up as it should be but when I enter the name and click confirm this happens[image]

The top buttons are squeezed off (they are still visible) while the button that I've just added seems to be cut off and I also can't use the scrollbar.

However, because I've written some code so that my program stores the name of the new playlist in a txt file and then gets this line to create the playlist buttons, whenever I rerun my program the griding seems to be just fine. (picture below)
The scrollbar works just fine as well.

[image]

Is there any way I can somehow update the grid so that it shows up as desired without (of course) rerunning the app?
I've tried `self.playlist_frame.update_idletasks()` but it doesn't seems to have any effect.
(where `self.playlists_frame` is the frame where I place the buttons and link the scrollbar to)
I've also tried recalling the function where I create the buttons when clicking the confirm button
but that seems to have no effect either
(when I say no effect I mean that the same thing happens)

Here is my code:

```
class MyApp:
    def __init__(self):

        self.root = tk.Tk()

        self.width = self.root.winfo_screenwidth()
        self.height = self.root.winfo_screenheight()
        self.height = self.root.winfo_screenheight() - int(self.height / 13)

        self.root.geometry(f'{self.width}x{self.height}')

        self.root.state('zoomed')
        self.root.resizable(False, True)

        self.c = '#14141D'

        self.playlists = {} 

        self.main = ttk.Notebook(self.root)

        # TABS
        self.home_tab = tk.Frame(self.main)
        self.playlists_tab = tk.Frame(self.main)
        self.manual_tab = tk.Frame(self.main)
       
        self.playlists_canvas = tk.Canvas(self.playlists_tab, bg=self.c)
        self.playlist_frame = tk.Frame(self.playlists_canvas, bg=self.c)
```

## this is how  I place the canvas, frame, scrollbar and the addplaylists button

```
    def widgets(self):
        self.playlist_frame = tk.Frame(self.playlists_canvas, bg=self.c)

        self.playlists_canvas.create_window((0,0),window=self.playlist_frame, anchor='center')
        self.playlists_canvas.config(bg=self.c)

        self.playlists_canvas.place(height=int(self.height / 1.428), width=self.width, x=0, y=int(self.height / 9))

        self.add_playlists_button = tk.Button(self.playlists_canvas, image=self.add_img, bg=self.c, bd=0,
                                              command=self.add_playlists)
        self.add_playlists_button.place(x=1284, y=75)

        self.playlists_scrollbar.pack(side='right', fill='y')
        self.playlists_canvas.config(yscrollcommand=self.playlists_scrollbar.set)
        self.playlists_canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: 
        self.playlists_canvas.configure(
            scrollregion=self.playlists_canvas.bbox('all')))
```

self.playlists is an empty dictionary that later (when  I add items to it) will get the form

```
self.playlists = {'rock':[], 'metal':[]}
```

which is a key: 'rock' with an empty list (so that I can later add songs)

I've made a function (create_playlists(self)) that appends the playlist buttons to a list and then grids the items of the same list.

```
def create_playlists(self):
    self.playlists_buttons_list = []

    for i in range(len(self.playlists.keys())):
        self.playlists_buttons_list.append(tk.Button(self.playlist_frame, bg=self.c,
                                                     text=' ' + list(self.playlists.keys())[i].split('!')[0],
                                                     height=280, width=300,
                                                     font=('Baskerville Old Face', int(self.height / 30)),
                                                     fg='pink', anchor='n',
                                                     activebackground=self.c, activeforeground='pink',
                                                     image=self.default_img,
                                                     compound=tk.LEFT, relief='sunken', overrelief='raised'))

    row = 0
    column = 0
    for i in self.playlists_buttons_list:
        if column > 3:
            row += 1
            column = 0

        if column > 7:
            row += 1
            column = 0

        i.grid(row=row, column=column)
        column += 1
```

And this is the function that is called when clicking the confirm button:

```
def get_name(self):
    self.name_of_plst = self.plst_entry.get()
    # self.plst_entry is the entry widget in the window that pops up
    if self.name_of_plst != '' and self.name_of_plst != '\n':
        self.playlists[self.name_of_plst] = []
        # this way I add an item to my dictionary ('name_of_new_playlist':[])
        self.create_playlists()
```

## ANYWAY here is a minimal reproducible example of what I'm running.

```
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


class MyApp:
    def __init__(self):

        self.root = tk.Tk()

        self.width = self.root.winfo_screenwidth()
        self.height = self.root.winfo_screenheight()
        self.height = self.root.winfo_screenheight() - int(self.height / 13)
        self.root.geometry(f'{self.width}x{self.height}')
        self.root.title("Mp3")

        self.c = '#14141D'

        self.playlists_buttons_list = []
        self.playlists = {}
        self.helping_d = {}

        self.main = ttk.Notebook(self.root)
        self.playlists_tab = tk.Frame(self.main)
        self.playlist_menu_frame = tk.Frame(self.playlists_tab, bg=self.c)
        self.playlists_canvas = tk.Canvas(self.playlists_tab, bg=self.c)
        self.playlist_frame = tk.Frame(self.playlists_canvas, bg=self.c)
        self.playlists_scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(self.playlists_tab, orient='vertical',
                                                 command=self.playlists_canvas.yview)
        self.add_playlist_win = tk.Toplevel(self.root)
        self.add_playlists_button = tk.Button(self.playlist_frame)
        self.default_img = Image.open('images/default.png').resize((75, 72))
        self.default_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.default_img)
        self.add_img = Image.open('images/add.png').resize((50, 50))
        self.add_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.add_img)
        self.widgets()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def widgets(self):
        self.playlists_tab.place(height=self.height, width=self.width, x=0, y=0)
        self.main.add(self.playlists_tab, text="Playlists")
        self.main.pack(expand=1, fill="both")
        self.playlist_frame = tk.Frame(self.playlists_canvas, bg=self.c)
        self.playlists_canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=self.playlist_frame, anchor='center')
        self.playlists_canvas.config(bg=self.c)
        self.playlists_canvas.place(height=int(self.height / 1.428), width=self.width, x=0, y=int(self.height / 9))
        self.add_playlists_button = tk.Button(self.playlists_canvas, image=self.add_img, bg=self.c, bd=0,
                                              command=self.add_playlists)
        self.add_playlists_button.place(x=1284, y=75)
        self.playlists_scrollbar.pack(side='right', fill='y')
        self.playlists_canvas.config(yscrollcommand=self.playlists_scrollbar.set)
        self.playlists_canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: self.playlists_canvas.configure(
            scrollregion=self.playlists_canvas.bbox('all')))

        if os.path.getsize('playlistsnames.txt') != 0:
            lines = open('playlistsnames.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8').read().splitlines()
            for i in lines:
                self.playlists[i] = []

        self.create_playlists()

    def create_playlists(self):
        self.playlists_buttons_list = []

        for i in range(len(self.playlists.keys())):
            self.playlists_buttons_list.append(tk.Button(self.playlist_frame, bg=self.c,
                                                         text=' ' + list(self.playlists.keys())[i].split('!')[0],
                                                         fg='white', image=self.default_img, height=280, width=300))
            row = 0
            column = 0
            for i in self.playlists_buttons_list:
                if column > 3:
                    row += 1
                    column = 0
                if column > 7:
                    row += 1
                    column = 0
                i.grid(row=row, column=column)
                column += 1

    def get_name(self):
        self.name_of_plst = self.plst_entry.get()
        self.playlists[self.name_of_plst] = []
        self.create_playlists()

        with open('playlistsnames.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as names_file:
            names_file.write(self.name_of_plst + '!\n')

    def add_playlists(self):
        self.add_playlist_win = tk.Toplevel(self.root)
        self.name_label = tk.Label(self.add_playlist_win, text='Name:', bg=self.c, fg='pink').pack()
        self.plst_entry = tk.Entry(self.add_playlist_win)
        self.plst_entry.pack()
        self.confirm_btn = tk.Button(self.add_playlist_win, text='Confirm', bg=self.c, fg='pink',
                                     command=self.get_name).pack()
        self.add_playlist_win.mainloop()


MyApp()
```

Comment: It's nice that you have broken down your program for us. It would be easier for us to help you if you show us how it all comes together.

Comment: @JacksonPro by showing how it all comes together you mean adding the whole code?

Comment: Yes, I must simply be able to copy the code and run the code (If it is too long post a minimal code that replicates the problem). Also, you pls remove unnecessary details and put more focus on what you want.

Comment: We do **not** need the whole program. We need a [mcve] with as little code as possible to duplicate the problem.

Comment: Ok I'm uploading my edit right now. Did my best to reduce any usnused code!

Comment: It should also be mentioned that in order for you to run it you should create a txt file where the data of the playlistnames are stored. Mine is named playlistsnames.txt - you can rename it however you want of course, but make sure you change tha name inside the ```os.path.getsize(filename)``` And also make sure to create 5 and then 9 playlists to have a better view of what happens